# How to enable the same queries from LGTM in Github CodeQL analysis

Tags: github, codeql

With LGTM.com being [shut down](https://github.blog/2022-08-15-the-next-step-for-lgtm-com-github-code-scanning/) I am looking to enable code analysis in Github to run the same analysis that lgtm.com does. At the first glance on Github's workflow, it seems to me it is only running a subset of scanning rules that are security related. I have found lgtm's default rules very useful (those that alerts unused imports etc.) How can I configure Github's code scanning to run the same rules as lgtm does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default CodeQL code scanning only runs security queries, but you can enable more queries as described [here in the documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/code-scanning/automatically-scanning-your-code-for-vulnerabilities-and-errors/configuring-code-scanning#using-queries-in-ql-packs):

```yaml
- name: Initialize CodeQL
  uses: github/codeql-action/init@v2
  with:
    # Run more security queries, and maintainability and reliability queries
    queries: security-and-quality
```

(though I am not sure if they are exactly the same queries which are used by LGTM.com; which queries are selected seems to be defined [here](https://github.com/github/codeql/blob/898689f5507e46f2cb63c988274ee940a5a30caa/misc/suite-helpers/lgtm-selectors.yml) and [here](https://github.com/github/codeql/blob/898689f5507e46f2cb63c988274ee940a5a30caa/misc/suite-helpers/security-and-quality-selectors.yml))

Comment: Thank you! Somehow I missed that section